# Problem on mechanics of bodies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, gravity

I am trying to solve this problem  [image]

- I thought using archimidis principle would be a way. the second body has more cavity than the first body(left body), i think, given that the 1st body will accelerate more in water. But both bodies have same weight, hence i also have a feeling this won't work.
- then i thought moment of inertia could be used to differentiate, the second body seems to have lesser moment of inertia,
  if i were to put both on an inclined plane the second one would roll down faster, i think.

is any of my approach correct, or am i missing something??

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. It breaks search functionality, and it doesn't work for blind users.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: It would help us if you could give a more descriptive title.  That helps us filter questions that we might be able to answer from those that we cannot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind next time.

Comment: As for references it's just a problem i got from an examination of a university my friend wrote, he asked me if i could solve and those are the possible methods i could think of, i just wanted to know if i was on the right track
.

Comment: Is this title more appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with your second idea.  The first sphere will have a larger moment of inertia , and will have a lower acceleration on an incline.

Comment: I thought this would work, just needed confirmation

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation